# Swipe to refresh Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I write something to a database, it will appear on the device, but when I remove it from the database, it stays in the app until I cut the app.

What should I code when I want to refresh the **Firebase database**?(
using swipeRefreshLayout)

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        }
    });
```

What do I write?

I write to database: "*sample text*"
The application will display: "sample text", then I deleted text from the database: "sample text", but the application is still showing: "*sample text*". I need **swipeRefreshLayout**, because I need refresh database in the application.

**Question**:
How can I refresh my UI when data is deleted from the database using **SwipeRefreshLayout**.

Comment: Please provide more detail. What is the data being displayed in?

Comment: In ListView....

Comment: just a question.... why would you remove it from the backend before removing it from the device? i would think the user wont have access to the backend.

Comment: I don´t know, what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is to tell the adapter that your data has changed using this line of code:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

A more common practice when it comes to Firebase is to use [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). This library will handle for you all events like items added, deleted or updated.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the Realtime or Live updates data entry which is showing in your UI to remove or refresh it on deletion just simple check if data exists using these callbacks.

Sample code: for listening to live updates (insertion or deletion)

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // ...
}
```

};

and this is your query to child reference

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child("chats")
        .limitToLast(50);
query.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

no need to use swipe refresh when you have callbacks for all the cases.

Comment: Is it something to do with SwipeRefreshLayout?

Comment: no, its firebase code callbacks for deltion or updation of live data.

Comment: But when I copy this code and insert to my project, this code:query.addChildEventListener(childEventListener); (childEventListener) 
is underlined red.                                                                                     And @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // ...
}  Override too

Answer (score 0):

Was facing same problem, and like said before, you can use the firebase code callbacks to do this, these links may help you.

Here's a [Udacity course](https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352?autoenroll=true) for firebase.

[Here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/ChildEventListener.html) you can also see how to implement these code callbacks, since [Udacity course](https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352?autoenroll=true) just shows the onChildAdded method.

And here's a link to [Firebase codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/?authuser=0#0), what solved the issue for me.

If you have evertything working, your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` should be instantiated like that, right?

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder>
        mFirebaseAdapter;
```

Then in your onPause and onResume methods just do like shown here and everytime you add, remove or change any data you're listening to in your database it will instantly be displayed in the app.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    mFirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
}
```

This way you don't need a `SwipeRefreshLayout`.
Give it a try. Works?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19220864)

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius thanks for the feedback, now it has the essential parts of the code needed.
If it helps share the answer please.